# Getting the user's local IP - Always getting 192.168.2.1

Tags: ip, httpcontext

I need to get the user's local IP for my ASP.NET application and I'm using this method:

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

    string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
    {
        string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
        if (addresses.Length != 0)
        {
            return addresses[0];
        }
    }

    return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

However, when I publish my website I always get **`192.168.2.1`** no matter where the user is opening the website from.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: `192.168.2.1` That's probably the router gateway. Is your server behind a router?

Comment: I need to check if the user opened the site from a certain range of IPs or not, but I cannot do this since I'm always getting 192.168.2.1 @AlvinWong

Comment: The current answers sort of prove a point made many times here - always post your relevant code, regardless of if it comes from a previous SO answer. Don't expect people to follow links to anywhere. =)

Comment: suggestion taken, post edited @J.Steen

Comment: The server is behind a router which uses port forwarding, so the connection is always to the router and NAT-ed to your server, so `REMOTE_ADDR` won't work. I think that's why `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` won't work either.

Comment: Then what can I use alternatively? For intance, http://jsonip.appspot.com/ works fine, but I will try to prevent user to connect to internet, but access it only locally, so he cannot open that site. @AlvinWong

Answer (score 0):

Some network devices make use of the [`X-forwarded-for` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For). You should check if the requests hitting your application have this header.

Comment: The point that the poster said, code in the link is followed, means x-forwarded-for is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the client's IP address from `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` or `REMOTE_ADDR`.

```
var ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress ))
{
    ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

return ipAddress;
```

Comment: I tried exactly the same, but I always get 192.168.2.1 no matter where the user is opening the website from.

Comment: ... as OP already does, if he uses the code in the linked answer.